# Random numbers that souldn't count 0,7,8,9

Tags: visual-studio

```
Dim generator As New Random
Dim myRand1, myRand2, myRand3, myRand4, myRand5, myRand6 As Integer

TextBox1.Clear()
TextBox2.Clear()
TextBox3.Clear()
TextBox4.Clear()
TextBox5.Clear()
TextBox6.Clear()
TextBox7.Clear()
TextBox8.Clear()
TextBox9.Clear()
TextBox10.Clear()
TextBox11.Clear()
TextBox12.Clear()

myRand1 = generator.Next(11111, 66666)
myRand2 = generator.Next(11111, 66666)
myRand3 = generator.Next(11111, 66666)
myRand4 = generator.Next(11111, 66666)
myRand5 = generator.Next(11111, 66666)
myRand6 = generator.Next(11111, 66666)

TextBox1.Text = myRand1.ToString()
TextBox3.Text = myRand2.ToString()
TextBox5.Text = myRand3.ToString()
TextBox7.Text = myRand4.ToString()
TextBox9.Text = myRand5.ToString()
TextBox11.Text = myRand6.ToString()
```

I have tried now a while to find out how to make it. I want to make numbers from 11111 to 66666 but I do not want to have 0,7,8,9 in these numbers. How am I supposed to do?

Comment: Um, throw a die five times (i.e. pick five random integers from 1 to 6), then concatenate?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct implementation available from .Net libraries. However you can override `public virtual int Next(int minValue, int maxValue)`method of the `Random` class with your custom implementation.

Comment: So what am i supposed to do ? :D im kinda new to this

Comment: In the overridden method, if `base.Next` returns 0,7,8,9 numbers, substitute those values with your own random number algorithm and return it.